# How remove margin in a paragraph that continues in two pages?

Tags: margins

I've created a document whose margins have different odd and even pages. I want to write a paragraph with no margin in two pages runs. If I use the command `\newgeometry` new paragraph starts at the top of new page, that I want to start at the same place. And the command `\begin{adjustwidth}{}{}` such marginalized different odd and even pages are not useful. Please guide me in this regard. I use this command for create margin:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 
‎‎\usepackage[total={215mm,285mm}‎,‎top=3cm,bottom=3cm,headsep=10pt,
    vmargin=2cm,
    outermargin=7cm,
    innermargin=2.5cm,
    marginparwidth=5cm,
    marginparsep=10pt]{geometry}
    \reversemarginpar‎
      ‎\usepackage{changepage}‎
      \usepackage{lipsum}‎
          ‎\begin{document}‎‎
               \lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]\lipsum[5]
 \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5cm}‎‎‎
  \lipsum[6]\lipsum[6]
  \end{adjustwidth}           
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm‎, ‎right=2.5cm}‎
‎ ‎‎\lipsum[6]\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newgeometry` will always shipout a `\clearpage` command. Is that what you want? I do not understand your question really. Can you upload some example, a sketch what you want to achieve?

Comment: \newgeometry starts the paragraph in new page but i want  start in same page.